# How to draw bounding boxes for predicted classes for a custom trained image classifier using fastai

Tags: bounding-box, fast-ai

I have created and guns and knives image classifier using fastai model resnet34. I am able to predict the class in an image but I want to extend it for real time analysis of a video footage. I want to get bounding boxes around the guns and knives but am not able to understand how I can get this. Can somebody please guide me through.

Answer (score 1):

So I would do it in two steps. First, learn how to get bounding boxes in fastai. Example [here](https://github.com/radekosmulski/whale/blob/master/fluke_detection_redux.ipynb).

If you have that you can use opencv to load a video frame by frame and label it. [OpenCV example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/).

When you have both it's quite easy to do it in real time. Just label frames loaded from your webcam. This process is quite expensive so you probably want to lower image resolution before inference. I've done it in tensorflow and it worked quite nicely. [This repository was extremely useful](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)